# Fish $EDITOR interaction

Tags: fish

How can I launch the currently configured editor from the `fish` shell?  That is the editor associated with `$EDITOR`.

What would a function look like that takes input from the pipeline and opens it in the editor identified by `$EDITOR`.

What would a function look like that opens a path in `$EDITOR` from the argument list?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
function edit -d "Open a file using $EDITOR"
    for file in $argv
        if test -e $file
            eval $EDITOR $file
            echo "Opening file $file"
        else
            echo "Create file? (y/n)"
            read createFile
            if test $createFile = "y"
                eval $EDITOR -n $file
                echo "Creating file $file"
            end
        end
    end
end
```